# C# Form inheritance issue

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I have a base form with a label & 2 buttons, when I inherit it in a child form, it only gets the label but not the buttons

I have no idea why is it inheriting one control but not the other, do you?

what I tried to do about it:

1- changed controls modifiers in base-form to protected then public, still only the label gets inherited

2- crated a new empty test project with a from with a text box and a button & a child form inheriting it, it works fine ie both controls appear on the child form

3- back to my project, I deleted the forms(parent & child) recreated the base form with a label and 2 buttons on default settings (without customization like font, text or size) then created the child form inheriting it, up till here it works fine all the controls appear on the child form.. once I customized the controls on the parent's constructor the buttons disappeared from the child only the label remained

**code sample:**

MainEdit form design file auto generated by VS2012

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Label editheader_lbl;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button cancel_btn;
private System.Windows.Forms.Button save_btn
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.editheader_lbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cancel_btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.save_btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // editheader_lbl
        // 
        this.editheader_lbl.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top;
        this.editheader_lbl.AutoSize = true;
        this.editheader_lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(164, 11);
        this.editheader_lbl.Name = "editheader_lbl";
        this.editheader_lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 13);
        this.editheader_lbl.TabIndex = 7;
        this.editheader_lbl.Text = "edit info";
        this.editheader_lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // cancel_btn
        // 
        this.cancel_btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(321, 278);
        this.cancel_btn.Name = "cancel_btn";
        this.cancel_btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.cancel_btn.TabIndex = 9;
        this.cancel_btn.Text = "cancel";
        this.cancel_btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // save_btn
        // 
        this.save_btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(143, 278);
        this.save_btn.Name = "save_btn";
        this.save_btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.save_btn.TabIndex = 8;
        this.save_btn.Text = "save";
        this.save_btn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // MainEdit
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(533, 331);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.cancel_btn);
        this.Controls.Add(this.save_btn);
        this.Controls.Add(this.editheader_lbl);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "MainEdit";
        this.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
        this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.TopMost = true;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
```

MainEdit.cs

```
public MainEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.editheader_lbl.Font = Program.font_l;
        this.save_btn.Font = Program.font_btn;
        this.save_btn.Size = Program.btnSize;
        this.save_btn.Text = Constants.SAVE;
        this.cancel_btn.Font = Program.font_btn;
        this.cancel_btn.Size = Program.btnSize;
        this.cancel_btn.Text = Constants.CANCEL;
    }
```

Edit_Employee.cs .. child form

```
public partial class Edit_Employee : MainEdit
{
    public Edit_Employee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**update**

by accident, the mouse button was pressed while I was moving and it made a selection area on the child form. there are 2 lock symbols where the buttons supposed to be, I guess that means the buttons are there but I just can't see them!
I'll go try out the suggestions I received till now and keep you updated, thanks for everyone who helped so far

**update -2**

tried adding the customization one by one to see what's causing this issue and it's the size line. though it takes the correct size in runtime, in design time it's like been set to 0,0 in the child! I get the resize points all next each other on the button I applied the size in the parent while the other button is displayed normally.

still don't see where the size edit is causing the trouble but I guess this question is solved by @Chiel92 hope you post your suggestion as answer so I can accept it and close this thread

thanks again

Comment: How is it not inheriting? You mean that the buttons are not visible on the child form?

Comment: @Chiel92 yes, the label gets on child form but no buttons. when I changed the default private into protected I can access the buttons via code but still they're not shown on the form

Comment: Are you sure the location of the buttons are within the child forms size?

Comment: @Chiel92 hmm I didn't change the child's size so it has to have inherited it from parent

Comment: You said it worked with the default values, so redo your customizations one by one, and see at which point the buttons disappear.

Comment: The buttons are probably overlapped by something else in the inherited form, maybe a panel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must call the base constructor:

```
public partial class Edit_Employee : MainEdit
{
    public Edit_Employee() : base() // See this line.
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then you don't need call InitializeComponent().

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue come from  the auto  generated part of your main form as with drag and drop  visual studio  will generate the parts  of your  main Form  as private  try to define all  your controls that should be inherited  in  your main class  not in the partial one generated by the designer something like this

MainEdit.cs(not the partial one generated by visual studio)

```
public partial class  MainEdit
{
protected System.Windows.Forms.Label editheader_lbl;
protected System.Windows.Forms.Button cancel_btn;
protected System.Windows.Forms.Button save_btn
public MainEdit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = string.Empty;
        this.editheader_lbl.Font = Program.font_l;
        this.save_btn.Font = Program.font_btn;
        this.save_btn.Size = Program.btnSize;
        this.save_btn.Text = Constants.SAVE;
        this.cancel_btn.Font = Program.font_btn;
        this.cancel_btn.Size = Program.btnSize;
        this.cancel_btn.Text = Constants.CANCEL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried changing the modifiers into protected, I can access the controls via code but they still not shown on the form. or do you mean I should not use the auto generated form at all and just write it on my own?

Comment: do you mean I should not use the auto generated form at all and just write it on my own?  yes that what I  mean